# What is single object localization?

Tags: computer-vision, terminology, object-detection, object-recognition

Object detection is said to be combination of object localization and image classification. However, when reviewing localization, I often come across the term "single-object" localization, but I am having trouble finding an accurate definition. What is "single-object" referring to?

[image: image from ImageNet Large Scale Visual Recognition Challenge]

Comment: Can you please provide more context? Where did you find the term _'"single-object" localization'_?

Comment: its in the picture that I have attached?

Comment: Yeah, but maybe provide the paper, article, or whatever, where you found that picture?